Creating raster mbtiles at high zoom level as overlay almost impossible with QGIS
I want to create a custom raster tile overlay uptil max zoom 18 (or further if possible) as mbtiles.
The scenario is like this, we have a library with cool motorcycle routes (especially in europe) and we want to show customers where they are as an overlay to base maps.
I know vector tiles could do this, I succesfully used tippecanoe to create vector tiles. But I found that rendering many custom polylines on a map (upto 30k road sections for a small country) has a high performance impact clientside (especially of course zooming out) and the map engine we want to use only supports their own vector tiles. So we would prefer raster tiles.
I use osmosis to read write and filter OSM data, ogr2ogr to create a GeoJSON, and QGIS for generating the mbtiles.
qgis_process run qgis:tilesxyzmbtiles --PROJECT_PATH=/home/mra/source/qgis/qgis_project/project.qgz --DPI=600 --EXTENT=3.278495620,7.326316180,50.404362650,53.777546450 --METATILESIZE=20 --OUTPUT_FILE=/home/mra/source/cli_test1_zm2tm18.mbtiles --ZOOM_MAX=18 --ZOOM_MIN=2

Once I have the mbtiles file I use maptiler/tileserver-gl to serve them. Works fine...
... however, upscaling this seems to be the problem. When I try to generate a mbtiles file uptil zoom level 18 (I run this on a Mac Air M3, 12 Cores, 24G Ram) it takes a very long time.
I was benchmarking the qgis_process command on a VM with normal specs (4 cores, 32G ram) and zoom level 2 till 16 takes 8h for a small country. I tried playing around with some of the CLI flags but it's all about the same. I might be missing something or it could be very much expected that creating so many PNG files takes this long.
I know gdal_rasterize could also be used also to create mbtiles in combination with gdal_translate but choosing the right resolution and width/heigth baffles me.
Does somebody have ideas or suggestions how I would go about creating raster mbtiles till zoomlevel 18 (or 20)?

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] this Question to focus on one specific issue

Got it! I updated the question to include one question.
